# android webview cache image

Tags: android, caching, webview

Here is my coding

```
webView1.loadUrl("http://www.ppshein.com.mm/testimage.jpg");
```

What I want is I want to cache this image when image is completely loaded in webview. That's why it can be able to display when device is offline.

Comment: May be this will help to You http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/

Answer (score 2):

Add the next lines:

`mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);`
`mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);`

Answer (score 0):

you can open cacheMode.when your img downloaded，it will be in the/data/data/your packagename/cache the directories below